# Mesh gets deformed when parenting to armature

Tags: rigging

[image]

[image]

I used rigify. How to fix this? Here's the file: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Copy Transforms* constraint of these bones needs to be set to *Local Space*, not *World Space*:

[image]

These bones are available in this layer:

[image]

Comment: I have a question, when I move the head the hat doesn't move with it, why?

Comment: You need to do an Alt H to see the controller bones, some bones move the head but I'm not familiar enough with Rigify or Auto-Rig to tell you how it is supposed to work